# How to get a secret using Terraform from AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a secret `foo` defined in AWS Secrets Manager. I have both the path and ARN for it and I would like to get it as a `data` resource in Terraform. I have created it via the same user I am trying to run the Terraform script.

What is the correct way to retrieve this secret while running Terraform, so that I don't have to expose the secret as part of my Git repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be achieved by a combination of two data sources.

**Data Source:** `aws_secretsmanager_secret`

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "by-arn" {
  arn = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:foo"
}
```

**Note:** Getting it based on ARN as you have mentioned you have access to it, otherwise can be done with name also.

**Data Source:** `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version`

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret-version" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.by-arn.id
}
```

The secret data can be then used in the way you want, one example would be

```
output "secret-value" {
  value = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string)["key1"]
}
```

Source:

- [secretsmanager_secret](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/secretsmanager_secret)
- [secretsmanager_secret_version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/secretsmanager_secret_version)